# NetSuite - Hide components of Item Group on Sales Order "Print PDF" forms

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, itemgroup

I have a client script deployed to NetSuite Sales Order record. This client script is responsible to add "Item Group" main line, then corresponding "Member Item" lines and finally "End of Group" line.

**Note:** The functionality is:

1. When a user adds an Item Group in Sales Order line, a Suitelet (Pop-Up window) immediately opens up displaying the corresponding components of the Item Group.
2. And the user can manually select the components required for that Item Group.
3. And on saving the form, the Suitelet window closes and the Sales Order client script triggers to add the Item Group line, selected member component lines and End of Group line on Sales Order.

**And my problem is:**

1. On the "Item Group" item record, "Display Components on Transactions" field is unchecked.
2. Due to which, based on standard NetSuite functionality, when the particular Item Group is manually added on Sales Order, the print PDF should display the main Item Group line only.
3. But on creating the Item Group line, member component lines and End of Group lines using client script; the Sales Order print PDF is displaying all set of lines (and not just Item Group line).

So how do I go about fixing the same and mimick standard NetSuite functionality (of only showing Item Group line when "Display Components on Transactions" field is unchecked).

**Additional Note**
I am currently using Sales Order's Basic PDF template. Any solution with Advanced PDF template would be more than welcome.

Thank you for your time in going through the same.